# In Java, given an array of object references, how do I check that all the references in the array are the same?

Tags: java

We just started learning references in Java and this one stumped me a bit. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `if (a == b)`  ? What have you tried?

Comment: (In a `for` loop ....)

Comment: add them all to a set, then check if the size of the set is 1?  Would work only if you don't have an equals() method on your list elements...

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the array and use == to compare the first array member against all others.

If there is any mismatch, you can stop, knowing that at least one entry is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method **equals** in **Arrays** utility class.

More info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-

Comment: `Arrays.equals()` uses `Object.equals()` to compare elements, which might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Equality operator will work to check if they have same reference and point to same object. eg:

```
array[0]==array[1]
```